# Change the font of all ggplot-outputs once in code instead of with every plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

Working with a quite huge R Markdown document, I was wondering whether it is possible to define the the font of my ggplots once in some kind of global setting? Just like I can use `theme_set()` to define `theme_minimal()` for all the plots in the document.

I tried adding something like this, but it threw an error:

```
theme_set(text = element_text(size=12, family="Times New Roman"))
```

Is this possible or would I have to define the font for each of my outputs individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your custom settings in `theme()`:

```
theme_set(theme(text = element_text(size=12, family="Times New Roman")))
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I add `theme_minimal()` in the same `theme_set()` function?

Answer (score 1):

To answer @SnupSnurre, yes.  To tweak an existing theme you can say. for example:

```
theme_set(theme_minimal() + theme(text = element_text(size=12, family="Times New Roman")))
```

to make global changes or

```
ggplot() + ...
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(size=12, family="Times New Roman")
```

to modify an individual plot

Comment: I'd add this to your previous answer as an update

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. However, when I knit the Markdown file, the font goes back to ggplots default? I've added cairo to the setup chunk: `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = "cairo_pdf")`